# Typescript Async/Await Need solution for ES5?

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await

I just found out that async/await in TypeScript isn't supported unless you use ES6, which we cannot use. TypeScript 2.0 beta is coming out "still" without this feature.

What solution can I use, can I do an "npm install promises" and use that, or does that require ES6 too? I do not want to roll my own solution here. Does anyone know of a npm package that can do async/await syntax without ES6?  We are doing pure node.js side coding.

Comment: I've had some success with having TypeScript target ES6 and then run it through Babel. TS verifies and removes the typing information; Babel converts ES6 to ES5.

Comment: I've seen some comments on that, it's too complicated a process for us, but thanks

Comment: You can install a promise library that will work with ES5 (I've used Bluebird in that circumstance).  But, you can't use async/await with that - those keywords require a Javascript interpreter that supports them.  You can use the promise library to program using promises though (not async/await).  Your other solution is to transpile your code to ES5 code using something like Babel.